# Webpack compile error: TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ … is not a function

Tags: javascript, file-upload, webpack, vue.js, vue-loader

So, this my Api Service Component, I'm using Axios:

```
import api from './Api.vue';

export default {
    name: 'app-feed-service',
    methods: {
        getPosts() {
            return api.get('posts/');
        }
    }
}
```

and some feed component

```
import AppSinglePost from './../Feed/Post.vue';
import AppFeedService from './../../api/Feed.vue';

export default {
    name: 'app-posts',
    components: {
        AppSinglePost
    },
    data() {
        return {
            posts: []
        }
    },
    created() {
        AppFeedService.getPosts().then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
}
```

and now the error:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__api_Feed_vue___default.a.getPosts is not a function
```

can anybody help?

Comment: Your feed service is called `Feed.vue`?

Comment: no why? it should?

Comment: That's what you are importing. `import AppFeedService from './../../api/Feed.vue'`

Comment: yeap. sorry misunderstood

Comment: I'm guessing you want to import `Feed.js` or something.

Comment: nope, Feed.vue, this is vue file format

Comment: Can you post the code for that?

Comment: Code for what? :) filename?

Comment: The error is talking about api_Feed_vue. What is the code for Feed.vue?

Comment: you have it above, first one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like AppFeedService as defined in Feed.vue is not really a component, it's just a collection of services you want to call. Since you have defined it as a component, the component would have to be *instantiated* somewhere, which in most cases would mean you used it in another component's `template`.

You can just define it as an object instead.

```
import api from './Api.js';

export default {    
    getPosts() {
        return api.get('posts/');
    }
}
```

Same thing for your Api.vue file likely. You only need to use a `.vue` file when you are defining an actual component.

Then in your feed component just

```
import AppFeedService from './../../api/Feed.js';
```

To summarize: the `.vue` file format is meant for defining single file *components*. You only need a `.vue` file when you are actually defining a single file component (something that would probably be used in the `template` of a different component). If you just want an object that contains a collection of methods or some state, just define it with plain javascript.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the exact same error as
**Webpack compile error: TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1** … is not a function**
in ReactJS.
This type of error you get usually when you are importing any defined variable/ component from any other file as Component. In react we import component as

`import ComponentName from '/componentPath';`

so if it isn't a component we are importing then try using importing as **an Object**

`import { componentName } from '/componentPath';`

The { } are the nameplates for an Object.